# android.R.Layout.* how to receive this as parameter on the method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I have a method that would receive the context and the List so it could change the background color of the adapter and return it, but now I have a situation that it must be either a `android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_1` for single line and `android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_2` or it could be any other type of `android.R.Layout.*`

How I can define the param on the method?

This is the method that I have for the moment

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterColor(List<String> list, Context context)
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = super.getView(position, converView, parent);
            if(position %2 == 1)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD6D6D6"));
            }
            else
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAFAFA"));
            }
            return view;
        }
    };
    return adapter;
}
```

I did try the Layout as param but doesn't work, I did search it but can't find info about this.

**Edit**

I wanted to do something like this:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> AdapterColor(List<String> list, Context context, Layout layoutParam)
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layoutParam, list)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = super.getView(position, converView, parent);
            if(position %2 == 1)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD6D6D6"));
            }
            else
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAFAFA"));
            }
            return view;
        }
    };
    return adapter;
}
```

Wanted to receive the `LayoutParam` from outside to the method, making the code more easy.

Comment: I suggest you to use your own CustomAdapter. How to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125744/5272951 . There you can parse any object from your activity you want. And you can set different colors by using `convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.parseColor("#FFFAFAFA") : Color.parseColor("#FFD6D6D6"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void setLayout(@LayoutRes int layoutRes){
    // do something with layoutRes
}

setLayout(R.layout.doggo)
```

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.html for more info

Comment: Ty the `@LayoutRes` did work, I did all rdy did try with the `int layoutRes` but did got an error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
View view = super.getView(position, converView, parent);
```

use the "converView" (or convertView, however you prefer :D ). Like so:

```
converView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD6D6D6"));
```

Comment: Ty, but that still doesn't answer my question :P let me edit the Question for better understanding

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yeah, you just have to link it to a List of objects, and read them.
Use the "position" parameter to get the item you want.
SomeObject someObject = someList.get(position);
Then simply read the data from the object model. In your case, read the color parameter from a method in the SomeObject model.

Comment: No worries but still not what I asked :p, I want is to receive as param on the method the `android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_1` or `android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_2`

Comment: Ok, last try :D You have to pass / accept an int, and pass the layout resource such as: R.layout.some_resouce. Android treats compiled layout resources as ints, so that's what you want. Simply, instead of (..., Layout layoutParam) use (... int layoutParam). Either that or set it on a View object and pass it. If this was helpful, I'll edit my answer so it can be helpful to others.

Comment: Ty but i did have tryed that all rdy, but adding the `@LayoutRes` before the int did worked, like wew lad as told on is answer